# jquery dialog will not close after clicking a URL

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have put a JQuery Dialog on my webpage to let visitors choose their language.
It worked fine for a little while, now it still works, except the box does not close when one of the URLs is clicked.
In the  tags I have the following code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#hello" ).dialog( {width:350},{ autoOpen: true });
    });
    </script>
```

In the  tag the following code appears:

```
<div id="hello" title="Welkom - Welcome!"><p align="center"><font face="Georgia" size="4">
Kies uw taal - Choose your language</font></p>
<div align="center"><a href="index.html">Nederlands</a> <a href="indexeng.html">English</a></div></div>
```

The popup appears, both links work, but, as I said, the only problem is, the box does not disappear when a URL is clicked.
I copied this code from [Udemy](https://blog.udemy.com/jquery-popup-window/) and made some adjustments to it, but, being the novice I am, I must have overlooked something.

If anyone could help me sort this out, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Where is your script code? in your matserpage/layout?

Comment: Just on my index.html page. The site is still under construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widget has a [`close`](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close) method. On click of your buttons you can just invoke it to close the model.

For example assume you have class `lang` on the div like:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#hello").dialog({
    width: 350,
    autoOpen: true
  });
  $('.lang a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#hello").dialog('close');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="hello">
  <div class="lang" align="center">
    <a href="index.html">Nederlands</a> 
    <a href="indexeng.html">English</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but the dialog is still not closing, or maybe I am not putting it in the right place. Could you show me where and how exactly I have to integrate it into the Java code  '<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#hello" ).dialog( {width:350},{ autoOpen: true });
    });
    </script>' (as I said, I am a complete novice in those things). Thanks again.

Comment: @user3592769 Can you put it right after `function(){ $( "#hello" ).dialog( {width:350},{ autoOpen: true });` inside the `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: @TJ1 Thank you, I did that, so the complete code is now `<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#hello" ).dialog( {width:350},{ autoOpen: true });
    });
 $('.lang a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#hello").dialog('close');
});
 </script>` but the window is still not closing. Without the curly bracket and semicolon before $('lang, the dialog just appears as text.

Comment: @user3592769 Your syntax is wrong. See the demo in answer.

Comment: Thanks again, but I really don't understand anymore now. I copied and pasted your code exactly as it was, the <link rel and <script src lines went in the <head> tags, the function bits too, within <script></script> tags, and the html within the <body></body> tags. All I get now is two hyperlinks at the top of the page, yet in the answer, your snippet works perfectly. I REALLY do not understand where I have gone wrong now.

Comment: @user3592769 press `f12` or right click and  open developer tools, check `console` tab and see if there's any error.

Comment: Seems to be resolved now. Looks like a script reference to jquery that was originally in my <head> tags was accidentally removed. Please let me know how I can give you a badge or other appreciation, as I am TRULY grateful for your help and patience.